# What is the most correct transcription of Ramesses II name?

Tags: ancient-egypt

[According to Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramesses_II), Ramesses name can be also transcribed as /ˈræmsiːz/ or /ˈræmziːz/

What is the most correct and how to prove this?

How to distinguish `s` and `z` correctness?

**UPDATE**

I met an opinion, that usage of `z` is VERY VERY wrong. And I am trying to find the basis of this. One of the reasonings was that the processes of turnin voiceless were finished in ancient egyptian language up to Middle Kingdom of Egypt, which was far before Ramesses II.

Comment: There is a whole subfield of linguistics dealing only with things like this. As such, this question is probably a bit expansive. The short answer is that it's quite possible that none are "most correct". If there was one that was "most correct" that's the one that would be used. The exception is when an early mistranscription has become commonplace. I don't know if this is the case with Ramses.

Comment: I suspect this is a question on how to pronounce the conventional name in English.

Comment: Here is a fairly extensive article on the pronunciation of Ancient Egyptian: http://www.friesian.com/egypt.htm

Comment: Well, pronouncing and transcribing are two completely different things.  /ˈræmsiːzandor /ˈræmziːz/ are quite likely both completely and utterly wrong as pronunciations of his name. They are two pronunciations of the transcription, which in turn is trying to just get as close as possible in the English-Latin script to how his name was written in hieroglyphs.

Comment: @LennartRegebro Why pronouncing and transcribing are different things? May be you mean transcribing and transliterating?

Comment: @Dims Transcribing and transliterating is also different things. The difference between /ˈræmsiːz/ or /ˈræmziːz/ is a difference between two different ways of **pronouncing** the **transliterated** spelling "Ramses". Are you actually asking how Ramesses name was pronounced in Ancient Egypt? Because that's a different question.

Comment: And with the different ways different letters are pronounced in different languages, you're getting different spellings dependent on which language a name is written down in. I don't think it's by now possible to find out how the name would have been pronounced by ancient Egyptians, as any remnants of the language will long since have been polluted by time and mixing with other languages.

Comment: The transliteration systems of Egyptian hieroglyphs are arcane in the extreme. Heiroglyphs were a complex icono-phonetic system and there is no one "correct" way to represent them with letters. You could argue that using letters at all is a bad practice. Hieroglyphs fundamentally represented ideas phonetic and otherwise, like Chinese characters, they do not represent fixed sounds in a sequence they way Western alphabets do.